# Rails query to retrieve related association for all query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Beginner @ rails here..  When using find_by_id I can retrieve the associated record but I'm unclear on how to do this through the all query. How can I adapt the find_by_id LEFT..JOIN for .all so it also retrieves the associated model.

My fail

```
@user = User.all.joins(:userpaintings).joins("LEFT JOIN paintings on userpaintings.painting_id = paintings.id")
```

This works

```
@user = User.find_by_id(1).joins(:userpaintings).joins("LEFT JOIN paintings on userpaintings.painting_id = paintings.id")
```

Comment: Do you want to get all users with theit paintings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@user = User.joins(:userpaintings).joins("LEFT JOIN paintings on userpaintings.painting_id =  paintings.id").all
```

`#all` will convert the relation into an Array, which you can't run methods such as `#joins` on.